# Cannot verify lock on path

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, delete-file, verify

When I want to delete some files, it happens to show me the error below:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   Cannot verify lock on path
>   'the file name...';
>   no matching lock-token available
>   If you want to break the lock, use the 'Check For Modifications' dialog.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

At least one of the files is locked. As the error tells you, use the "Check for Modifications" dialog, click on the "check repository" button and then find the files which have a lock on them. Then either remove, break of steal that lock.

Comment: so I did it , but nothing happened after check repository,so what can I do then?

Comment: worked for me! I swear, diff day, different problem. TG for S/O!

Comment: I have a similar problem. No files are locked though. At least according to the "Check for Modifications" dialog, even with "check repository" button pressed.

Answer (score 1):

- For client-side command line approach, you can run

  [`svn unlock --force problematic.file.name`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.unlock.html)
- An administrator who has local access to the repositories could run

  [`svnadmin unlock`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.unlock.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What command were you using to delete the files? Is this a local command or a remote command in Subversion?

```
$ svn rm file   #Local mode

$ svn http://svnhost/svn/project/trunk/file   #Remote mode
```

If you were deleting files in local mode, are they read-only? If so, you'll have to determine what made them read-only. Is there a lock on them? See the [Red Bean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html) book chapter on locks.

You were using a Subversion command. Right?

Comment: I checked for lock but find nothing about it. I use windows svn client "TortoiseSVN" to delete the files on remote server. Now I dump the repo and except these files. But it's not the best solution, please give me a hand,thanks.

Comment: Still trying to understand what you did: You directly deleted the files from the repository and didn't delete them from the local working directory. Right? What do you mean you "dump the repo", but these files? Did you do a `svnadmin dump`? Can you do a `svnadmin lslocks` on the repository?

Comment: I deleted the files from local but cannot commit then. And I did the `svnadmin dump`. `svnadmin lslocks` I do it which gave me the lock . So what should I do next?

Answer (score -1):

if you are in eclipse , go to team, click lock, then there is check box for (steal lock) click it and retry with check it , then it should work for you